# Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>, (<class 'list'> containing values of types {"<class 'int'>"}). How to fix?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from pickle import load
from numpy import argmax
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from keras.models import load_model
from nltk.translate.bleu_score import corpus_bleu

# load a clean dataset
def load_clean_sentences(filename):
    return load(open(filename, 'rb'))

# fit a tokenizer
def create_tokenizer(lines):
    tokenizer = Tokenizer()
    tokenizer.fit_on_texts(lines)
    return tokenizer

# max sentence length
def max_length(lines):
    return max(len(line.split()) for line in lines)

# encode and pad sequences
def encode_sequences(tokenizer, length, lines):
    # integer encode sequences
    X = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(lines)
    # pad sequences with 0 values
    X = pad_sequences(X, maxlen=length, padding='post')
    return X

# map an integer to a word
def word_for_id(integer, tokenizer):
    for word, index in tokenizer.word_index.items():
        if index == integer:
            return word
    return None

# generate target given source sequence
def predict_sequence(model, tokenizer, source):
    prediction = model.predict(source, verbose=0)[0]
    integers = [argmax(vector) for vector in prediction]
    target = list()
    for i in integers:
        word = word_for_id(i, tokenizer)
        if word is None:
            break
        target.append(word)
    return ' '.join(target)

def predict_sequence_with_context(model, tokenizer, source, max_length):
    target_seq = [0]
    in_text = 'startseq'
    for _ in range(max_length):
        # encode the source sequence
        source = tf.expand_dims(source, axis=0)
        # predict next word
        yhat = model.predict([source, target_seq], verbose=0)
        # convert probability to integer
        yhat = argmax(yhat)
        # map integer to word
        word = word_for_id(yhat, tokenizer)
        # stop if we cannot map the word
        if word is None:
            break
        # append as input for generating the next word
        in_text += ' ' + word
        # stop if the end of the sequence is generated
        if word == 'endseq':
            break
        # update the target sequence
        target_seq = pad_sequences([tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([in_text])[0]], maxlen=max_length, padding='post')
    return in_text

# evaluate the skill of the model with context
def evaluate_model_with_context(model, sources, raw_dataset, max_length):
    actual, predicted = list(), list()
    for i, source in enumerate(sources):
        # translate encoded source text
        source = tf.convert_to_tensor(source)  # Convert to TensorFlow tensor
        source = tf.expand_dims(source, axis=0)  # Updated line
        translation = predict_sequence_with_context(model, eng_tokenizer, source, max_length)
        raw_target, raw_src = raw_dataset[i][:2]
        if i < 10:
            print('src=[%s], target=[%s], predicted=[%s]' % (raw_src, raw_target, translation))
        actual.append(raw_target.split())
        predicted.append(translation.split())

    # calculate BLEU score
    print('BLEU-1: %f' % corpus_bleu(actual, predicted, weights=(1.0, 0, 0, 0)))
    print('BLEU-2: %f' % corpus_bleu(actual, predicted, weights=(0.5, 0.5, 0, 0)))
    print('BLEU-3: %f' % corpus_bleu(actual, predicted, weights=(0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0)))
    print('BLEU-4: %f' % corpus_bleu(actual, predicted, weights=(0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25)))

# load datasets
dataset = load_clean_sentences('english-german-both.pkl')
train = load_clean_sentences('english-german-train.pkl')
test = load_clean_sentences('english-german-test.pkl')

# prepare english tokenizer
eng_tokenizer = create_tokenizer(dataset[:, 0])
eng_vocab_size = len(eng_tokenizer.word_index) + 1
eng_length = max_length(dataset[:, 0])
print('English Vocabulary Size: %d' % eng_vocab_size)
print('English Max Length: %d' % (eng_length))

# prepare german tokenizer
ger_tokenizer = create_tokenizer(dataset[:, 1])
ger_vocab_size = len(ger_tokenizer.word_index) + 1
ger_length = max_length(dataset[:, 1])
print('German Vocabulary Size: %d' % ger_vocab_size)
print('German Max Length: %d' % (ger_length))

# prepare data
trainX = encode_sequences(ger_tokenizer, ger_length, train[:, 1])
testX = encode_sequences(ger_tokenizer, ger_length, test[:, 1])

trainX = np.array(encode_sequences(ger_tokenizer, ger_length, train[:, 1]))
testX = np.array(encode_sequences(ger_tokenizer, ger_length, test[:, 1]))

trainX = tf.convert_to_tensor(trainX)
testX = tf.convert_to_tensor(testX)
# load model
model = load_model('model.h5')

# test on some training sequences with context
print('train')
evaluate_model_with_context(model, trainX, train, eng_length)

# test on some test sequences with context
print('test')
evaluate_model_with_context(model, testX, test, eng_length)
```

```
English Vocabulary Size: 2172
English Max Length: 5
German Vocabulary Size: 3554
German Max Length: 8
train
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-0c62df700bde> in <cell line: 128>()
    126 # test on some training sequences with context
    127 print('train')
--> 128 evaluate_model_with_context(model, trainX, train, eng_length)
    129 
    130 # test on some test sequences with context

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/data_adapter.py in select_data_adapter(x, y)
   1103     if not adapter_cls:
   1104         # TODO(scottzhu): This should be a less implementation-specific error.
-> 1105         raise ValueError(
   1106             "Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: {}, {}".format(
   1107                 _type_name(x), _type_name(y)

ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: (<class 'list'> containing values of types {'(<class \'list\'> containing values of types {"<class \'int\'>"})', "<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor'>"}), <class 'NoneType'>
```

Link for the dataset is as follows:
http://www.manythings.org/anki/deu-eng.zip

modify the code so that each target sentence word is conditional on the preceding words of the target sentence, you'll need to adjust the predict_sequence function. Additionally, you'll need to modify the training part to incorporate the feedback loop from previously generated words to the model input

Comment: Hi Sanjit, You will need to adjust the predict_sequence function to use the previously generated words as context for generating the next work. We will also modify the training part to incorporate the feedback loop from previously generated words to the model input.